# Add multiple array values to a list is possible in scala?

Tags: arrays, list, scala

How to add array values a & b (multiple values) to List list1

```
  var list1:java.util.List[Array[String]]=List[Array[String]]()

  var a=Array[String]("Excellent","Good","Need To Improve")

  var b=Array[String]("1","2","3")

  list1.add(a)
  list1.add(b)
```

I tried this but the Array values not add to the List

The array values not add to list

Comment: Your first line does not compile because you are mixing two kinds of Lists.  Did you mean to use a scala List or a Java List?

Comment: @dhg java list to scala List

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possiblities for java.util.ArrayList (which is mutable):

```
scala> val list = new java.util.ArrayList[Array[String]]()
list: java.util.ArrayList[Array[String]] = []


scala> var a=Array[String]("Excellent","Good","Need To Improve")
a: Array[String] = Array(Excellent, Good, Need To Improve)

scala>  var b=Array[String]("1","2","3")
b: Array[String] = Array(1, 2, 3)

scala> list.add(a)
res8: Boolean = true

scala> list.add(b)
res9: Boolean = true

scala> list
res10: java.util.ArrayList[Array[String]] = [[Ljava.lang.String;@4786b9ce, [Ljava.lang.String;@5e10a811]
```

Or for scala List (immutable) - you have reassign list :

```
scala> var list = List[Array[String]]()
list: List[Array[String]] = List()

scala> list = b :: a :: list
list: List[Array[String]] = List([Ljava.lang.String;@5e10a811, [Ljava.lang.String;@4786b9ce)
```